# Is it reasonable to consider logs as a "technical control"?

Tags: logging, terminology, ccsp

I'm studying for the CCSP exam and one of the examples of technical controls (referenced in the course training material) confuse me:

> Technical controls, also referred to as logical controls, are those
>   controls that enhance some facets of the CIA triad, usually operating
>   within a system, often in electronic fashion.  Possible technical
>   controls include encryption mechanisms, access control lists to limit
>   user permissions, and audit trails and **logs of system activity**.

Can someone please explain why logs, in and of themselves, can be considered a technical control?  To me, it seems like logs would be something that's not a control by itself, but a resource that aides other technical controls (like  an alert monitor that reviews log material and warns administrators, etc).

Comment: detection control

Comment: I got this by searching "logs as technical control" https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/shared/documents/itl-bulletin/itlbul1997-03.txt ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logs are a **detective control** - they allow you to detect activities that you would like to control.  Obviously, they do it in an electronic fashion, making them a technical control by the definition you've provided (as opposed to procedural controls, for example).

You seem to be thinking more of **preventive controls**, which block activity you would like to control before it happens.  Technical controls are often preventive, by their nature, but they don't need to be.

Distinctions like **technical** and **procedural** indicate *how* a control works.  Distinctions like **preventive** and **detective** indicate *when* a control works.

Comment: Thanks for your insight and patience.  I'm pretty sure I'm overthinking this...  I guess I'm still struggling to understand how log information _by itself_ is a detective control? Wouldn't a detective control be some security measure or tool that is reviewing/reading/parsing the log data and performing some action based on it?

Comment: Nevermind. On the 4th time reading your answer, I think it "clicked".  Thanks.

Comment: To say that "logs" are a technical control is to say that "the generation, transmission, parsing, storage, and usability for searching and alerting of logs" is a technical control.